# Correctly include jUnit5 @Nested classes when running single class in maven

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

The `@Nested` classes that are executed in JUnit 5 they are ordered to run AFTER all the tests in eclosing class. How could I enforce the same behavior using maven, if my goal is to run a single enclosing class and it's nested classes? Is there a commandline or pom.xml modification to make this example test pass?

```
package example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SomeTopLevelTest {

    private static boolean nestedDone = false;

    @Test
    void test1() {
        Assertions.assertFalse(nestedDone, 
            "Nested classes should execute after the enclosing tests");
    }

    @Nested
    class SomeNestedTest {
        @Test
        void test2() {
            nestedDone = true;
        }
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void recheck() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(nestedDone, "Nested class should be executed");
    }
}
```

This does pass in IDE:
[image]

But does not in commanline, if I try to specify the name:

```
mvn test -Dtest=example.SomeTopLevelTest

[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   SomeTopLevelTest.recheck:27 Nested class should be executed ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>


mvn test -Dtest=example.SomeTopLevelTest*
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   SomeTopLevelTest.test1:14 Nested classes should execute after the enclosing tests ==> expected: <false> but was: <true>
```

Comment: Can you tell where it's defined `@Nested classes that are executed in JUnit 5 they are ordered to run AFTER all the tests`? Furthermore if you have unit tests you should not rely on any order if you need to you should check for Order Annotation in Junit Jupiter...

Comment: Why do you use a static variable in your test class ? For what purpose?

Comment: @khmarbaise "where it's defined?": the closes to official source I have found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/55482937/1374322 - trustworthy as it comes from sam-brannen, project maintainer.

"Why static variable?" - to demnstrate the problem.

Comment: Yes I know who Sam Brannon is but I would never rely on such thing. Second how is Maven configured? Which Maven version do you use? Which version of maven-surefire-plugin do you use? And how does your pom file look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of `@Nested` classes not executing is a known issue and it has been reported in both [JUnit5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1343) and [Surefire](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE/issues/SUREFIRE-1633) issue trackers, but as of now remains unresolved.

The current state of affairs (tested with Maven 3.6.3, Junit5 5.7.2, Surefire 2.22.2 up to 3.0.0-M5):

### A. Not selecting a test

```
mvn test
```

Results in executing all test classes as expected: methods from enclosing classes first, and then methods from `@Nested` classes, level by level

### B. Selecting test the standard way

```
mvn test -Dtest=example.SomeTopLevelTest
```

This apparently triggers the default surefire `excludes` that use the following pattern:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/*$*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Why does it not happen in case A is a mystery, but one can override this behaviour by explicitly clearing the excludes pattern:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude/>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

It does not seem to be possible to do without modyfing the pom.xml.
This **DOES NOT** solve the issue as posted in this question, because the nested classes are still executed first.

### C. Using wildcard with -Dtest parameter

```
mvn test -Dtest=example.SomeTopLevelTest*
```

This explicitly selects all the nested classes, but - as stated in the question - results in executing the nested classes first, so it's not a solution.

### D. Using includes

```
mvn test -DtestName=example.SomeTopLevelTest

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>${testName}</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Apparently `include` patterns work quite differently than `-Dtest` parameter, because this is finally the solution to pass the test from the question. With this setup the `testName` may be a single class, wildcard pattern or regex

- `example.SomeTopLevelTest` to execute all test methods in single class
- `example/*` - all tests (including nested) in package example, but not sub-packages
- `example/**` - all tests in package and subpackages
- advanced regex, is supprted too

Comment: thank you for the last idea with `includes` - you saved our day.